# Android: Need Ellipsis for Multiple TextViews in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am new to Android, i have below task.

I want to align three TextViews adjacent to each other with ellipsis if the text is too long . Currently i am using below code which aligns my TextView adjacent to each other, but my problem is if the text is too long, the below code not putting the ellipsis. i got some trick to use both `toleftof` and `torightof` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686468/end-textview-with-3-dots-with-use-of-maxlength), but in my case it going to circular dependency as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284659/why-am-i-getting-a-circulardependencyexception).

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reminderText">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/noteTagOne"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/noteTagTwo"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noteTagOne"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/noteTagThree"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noteTagTwo"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

I want output as,

```
Tag1... Tag2... Tag3...
```

Basically, i want some ideas, whether in xml i can achieve this or need to do it programmatically, since TextView text's are dynamic i cannot fix maxLength, sometimes only single tag may exist, at that time it should take full text.

Note: I am developing Android project using C# in Xamarin.

[image]

Added code is for the above highlighted part. I fixed overlapping of tagsicon & text. Now only two issues.

1) Last tag is overlapping with right aligned image.
2) If TextView texts are short, gap is shown in-between the tags

How to fix it?

Comment: use `LinearLayout` and set `orientation` as horizontal and having `weightSum = "3"`. Now keep three `TextView`s inside this `LinearLayout` with each `TextView` having `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_width="0dp"`...

Comment: Thanks, working great, but before these three TextView i am having one ImageView, if i added that, first tag is not getting ellipsized...

Comment: is that imageview should take a space equal to space of individual TextView?

Comment: Yes, its size is 16X16, but if i added inside LinearLayout along with TextView means, image becomes too wide, by adding outside its getting overlapped with first TextView text.

Comment: then use `android:drawableLeft` attribute for first textview...

Comment: with android:drawableLeft, icon itself is not shown. Also i am having some text with layout_alignParentRightof. Last tag is getting overlapped with right aligned text without putting ellipsis, but first one truncated with ellipsis

Comment: post a screen shot what u want to achieve...

Comment: if you are using `RelativeLayout`, then your `LinearLayout` containing `TextView`s should be right to link image and left to folder image

Comment: Except gap, its working fine, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteTagOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Tag111111111111111111"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteTagTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noteTagOne"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Tag2222222222222222"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteTagThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noteTagTwo"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Tag3333333333333333"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Its working, but is it possible to achieve this without fixing the width, because if the text is small, gap is shown in between tags, it looks odd...

Comment: Please let me know.If i am chat smiley icon ellipsize is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this android:ellipsize="marquee" it will work

Comment: But with android:ellipsize="marquee", whether am i able to get dots(...) at the end? Basically i doesn't want the ellipsized text to be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

or

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```